# Customizing Legend Border Color in eCharts4r Plot

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

I am working on an `echarts4r` plot where I have customized symbols, and I want the legend to match these symbols along with specific border colors. The plot is based on the following example data:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

the_data <- data.frame(
  key = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
  group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
  x = c(0.495, -0.466, 0.85, 1.06, -0.441, 0.395), 
  y = c(1.06, 0.82, 3.76,3.17, 0.49, 2.67), 
  color = c("#FFFF00", "#FFA500", "#FFFF00", "#FFA500", "#FFFF00", "#FFA500"), 
  symbolSize = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), 
  borderColor = c("#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#0000FF", "#FF0000", "#0000FF"), 
  symbol = c("rect", "rect", "circle", "circle", "diamond", "path://M27,34.44 L29.87,29.47 L24.13,29.47 Z"
))
```

If I generate the plot without configuring the legend, there is a discrepancy between the elements in the plot and the legend.

```
the_data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  echarts4r::e_chart(x) %>%
  echarts4r::e_scatter(y,
                       itemStyle = list(borderWidth = 2)) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_unnested("symbol", symbol) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_unnested("symbolSize", symbolSize) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_nested("itemStyle", color, borderColor)
```

[image]

Subsequently, I attempted to configure the legend. While I managed to successfully define the shapes and colors for the legend, I encountered challenges in setting the `borderColor` specifically for the legend items. The current approach involves utilizing `borderColor` within the `itemStyle`. An alternative method explored was using `echarts4r::e_add_nested("itemStyle", color, borderColor)`, which had already been employed for implementing `borderColor` in `echarts4r::e_scatter()`. However, it seems to have no discernible effect in the context of the legend customization.

```
legend_data <- the_data %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(group, color, borderColor, symbol) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(group)

the_data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  echarts4r::e_chart(x) %>%
  echarts4r::e_scatter(y,
                       itemStyle = list(borderWidth = 2)) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_unnested("symbol", symbol) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_unnested("symbolSize", symbolSize) %>%
  echarts4r::e_add_nested("itemStyle", color, borderColor) %>%
  echarts4r::e_color(color = legend_data$color) %>%
  echarts4r::e_legend(
    itemWidth = 15,
    itemStyle = list(
      borderColor = legend_data$borderColor,
      borderWidth = 2,
      itemWidth = 15
    ),
    icons = legend_data$symbol
  )
```

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with echarts4r but in echarts itself the symbol configured in the series is automatically taken for the [legend](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.data). Note, that you have to specify [series name](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.name).

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6ADZsq0AUSQOS5HPk_8ZJQ0sgBujE5KtPaOsHhURlSEsKKBqKSkFNR0eExgLBy8gejQjAC2IbQAjEUZgsJiVQCsAAw8sABMAMxtnR0ALO0dVQAc7VVdTeP9AOxDAGwt1rEZeORlAEbATnRgRozQrC61dWub2yYQAF4hVYPFsBAsZSYULp7025x0G5HK7VsOAIEgBhL4cOgcDQyQHAjiqCACMDaIgdOyBbwZdJ1LKVXLMAonDKlCp0DpE0hCMAiFIdFq9Zq9bpMgZDUbjSbTGbLB5nLY7WR4ACOCkYUIp6D5F2ut3udUez1e5HeyE-Tm-snIVCc6oA7jDOHCweqIbIoZoAYaEgikSjOuiMpjSNiMricnlCStSCTKl0JbAqTTRABOBkjNqMoY9Iaszrs2ATJo8-VSpyXG5EO5e9BPKgvN4hJBqjW0TgHVj_WCw0Hgn5_A1A62I5Goh2kNu2OwAbiAA):

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  legend: {},
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      name: '1',
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      symbol: 'triangle',
      symbolSize: 14,
      itemStyle: {color: 'blue', borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 2}
    },
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      name: '2',
      data: [200, 150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147],
      symbol: 'square',
      symbolSize: 14,
      itemStyle: {color: 'yellow', borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 2}
    },
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      name: '3',
      data: [90, 180,150, 230, 224, 218, 135],
      symbolSize: 14,
      itemStyle: {color: 'orange', borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 2}
    }
  ]
};
```

---

I just noticed that customizing the symbol style in legend.data works also fine in plain echarts. So maybe its an issue in echarts4r :(

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I got your plot working and the legend works as expected. I've noticed that echarts4r::e_add_nested() places the variables under data. While this arrangement functions well for scatter points, it doesn't seem to be recognized by the legend.

```
....
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["Mon", "150"],
          "symbol": "triangle",
          "symbolSize": 14,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": "blue",
            "borderColor": "red"
          }
        }
      ],
      "name": "1",
```